# Force a custom resolution

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, resolution, graphics

I have a no-name graphic card that Windows can't recognize, so it just shows standard VGA in the device manager list.

Now it just shows 800x600 and 1024x768, but I want to force that to other resolutions; I'm sure it supports because I checked in Linux!

Comment: You need to install an appropriate driver. To do so you need to determine if the GPU chipset is *Intel*, *Nvidia*, *ATI/AMD* (or on the off-chance *other*). Since you mentioned **Linux**, if you have a LiveCD handy, run `lsmod | grep "^video "` and report back with the driver that the linux distro selected. You could also use `lspci | grep VGA` to get the specific chipset.

Comment: thnx for your reply, my friend create this card and it doesn't have any brand like you say, intel or ati or ..., my question is how we can force to other resolution that's all ?!

Answer (score 2):

This is untried/untested, do so at your own risk!

> Click on Start, then Run
>      Type in regedit in the Open box, then hit [Enter]
>      Expand down to HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Contr ol\VIDEO{Hexadecimal number for your primary video card}\0000
>           Note: Under VIDEO will be one or more registry keys that have a long hexadecimal number; this is the Hexidecimal number assigned to
>   a specific physical or logical video card. There may be more than one
>   if video cards have been changed or a major driver update has been
>   performed. The key that has the current setting should be the one that
>   needs to be modified.
>       Double-click DefautlSettings.XResolution, change the Base from Hexadecimal to Decimal notation, and set the X axis.
>       Double-click DefautlSettings.YResolution, change the Base from Hexadecimal to Decimal notation, and set the Y axis.
>       Reboot
>
> Note: If settings did not take effect, modify a different video card in the registry
>      Note: If monitor ceases to function upon Windows coming up, reboot and go to Safe Mode. Pull up the registry and change the settings that
>   were last modified back to the way it was or change the resolution to
>   a safe resolution such as 640x480.

[Source](http://www.mp3car.com/lcd-display/42122-tutorial-forcing-custom-resolution-in-windows.html)

There are also tools which may help, like [PowerStrip](http://entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm)

[Details on how to use it](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/customize-monitor-resolution-settings-with-powerstrip/)

Comment: thnx dave, I checked that before, but it won't work :(

Comment: @Mike Did you try both things?

Comment: yeah , before your reply I checked the registry method and after that PowerStrip, in PowerStrip it just show 1024x768 too, any idea??

Comment: @Mike Try this, I didn't read it all but it may help http://www.techrepublic.com/article/customize-monitor-resolution-settings-with-powerstrip/

Comment: Thanks Dave, but I don't know why it just show the 1024x768 and the other options are disable :(

Answer (score 0):

have a look and download 'million drivers' cd.

in device manager right click and update drivers - pointing it to the cd. it might take a few minutes but it should then detect the card.

once its installed the drivers. you should see its true name and go to the manufacturers website to get the latest drivers for the card.

Comment: What is that CD and where can it be obtained?

Answer (score 0):

1. Start Regedit

Click the Start Button,
Click Run
Type Regedit
Click Ok

2. Go to the right key

Go to HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\VIDEO{####-####-####}\0000

3. Modify Registry

Double click on DefaultSettings.XResolution
Check Decimal
Enter the value you want
Click Ok
Double click on DefaultSettings.YResolution
Check Decimal
Enter the value you want
Click Ok

4. Apply modifications

Close all windows
Restart Windows

5. If you have problems

If the new resolution you've set isn't support or you have any other problems, restart windows and repetively press F8 right after the BIOS is loaded. It will show you a debug menu. Select VGA mode option.